# Error : Logon failure : the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, window

I have one Asp. Net application that authenticated using window's Advapi logon process type 2 (interactive).

Getting error message

> login failed, the user name and password is incorrect

when I am trying to login using my user name and password. I was able to login in my old server, after migrating to new server only it is failing t login. I checked event log, getting some following use full error information but not able to figure out what is the actual issue.

```
Failure reason- the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.
Status - 0*C000015B
Logon Process - Advapi
Package name - NTLM only
Event code - 4625
```

I got some suggestion to resolve this issue by doing some changes in Local security policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Allow Logon Locally. But our AD group is there and I am in this group. It did not resolve login failed issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read this for changes in security: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/default-permissions-user-rights

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.